# how do i reorder my javascript code better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

i'd like to make my code neater and less confusing. here's the code:

```
  // NAV BAR  //
$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
 if($(window).width() > 980) {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
    //add black background
    $(".x-navbar").addClass("active");
    $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li  a").addClass("small-bar");
  } 
  else {
    //remove background
    $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
    $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
  }
 }else{
     // if window width < 980
     //remove background
    $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
    $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
 }
 });
```

what it does is simply gets the width of the screen and as soon as the user scrolls down, it restyles the header by giving it a smaller height and a different background using the classes active and small-bar. i got the code here and there so it's kinda messy, isn't there a way to write it in less strings and make it more efficient?

Comment: Seems like a codereview question

Comment: Efficiency/performance questions are off-topic here, but on-topic to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), especially if the code is working (as in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please use [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind or purposes (working code that needs a review).

Here's the review:

```
// 1. Store each selector into a variable
// 2. Create a method to do the job and use `.toggleClass()` with its second parameter
// 3. Work with events and calling to the method when necessary.

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
    var $win = $(this);
    var $target = $('.x-navbar');
    var $subselector = $('.desktop .x-nav li a', $target);

    /** 
     * @param {boolean} action Set to true to show, false to hide
     */
    var DoJob = function(action){
        $target.toggleClass('active', action);
        $subselector.toggleClass('small-bar', action);
    };

    if( $win.width() > 980 ){
        if( $win.scrollTop() > 20 ) DoJob(true);
        else DoJob(false);
    }
    else DoJob(false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do both checks at once, to remove duplicate code:

```
// NAV BAR  //
var $window = $(window);
$window.on("scroll resize", function() {
  var showBG = $window.width() > 980 && $window.scrollTop() > 20;
  if (showBG) {
    //add black background
    $(".x-navbar").addClass("active");
    $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li  a").addClass("small-bar");
  }
  else {
    //remove background
    $(".x-navbar").removeClass("active");
    $(".x-navbar .desktop .x-nav li a").removeClass("small-bar");
  }
 });
```

Comment: in his logic background removes every time when win width is less then 980, in your code if scroll is <=20 and win width is more than 980 then background will be removed and it doesn't require all states
you need to add `else if($win.width() <= 980){`

Comment: His else blocks were duplicated, so we only need one to work.  In both OP's and my code, background would be removed for the test you gave.  Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $win = $(window);
var nav = $(".x-navbar");
var navLinks = nav.find(".desktop .x-nav li  a");

$win.on("scroll resize", function() {
   if($win.width() > 980 && $win.scrollTop() > 20) {
     nav.addClass("active")
     navLinks.addClass("small-bar");
   } 
   else if($win.width() <= 980){
     nav.removeClass("active")
     navLinks.removeClass("small-bar");
   }
}
```